# Is there a way to "slow down" speed of wireless mouse middle button scrolling on 18.04?

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-18.04

Here is the mouse info:  anyway to *slow down* how fast it scrolls with the mouse wheel?

```
[I]  ~/bin  xinput --list-props 12Device 'Logitech Anywhere MX':
    Device Enabled (141):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (143): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled (276):       0
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled Default (277):       0
    libinput Scroll Methods Available (278):        0, 0, 1
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled (279):   0, 0, 0
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled Default (280):   0, 0, 0
    libinput Button Scrolling Button (281): 2
    libinput Button Scrolling Button Default (282): 2
    libinput Middle Emulation Enabled (283):        0
    libinput Middle Emulation Enabled Default (284):        0
    libinput Accel Speed (285):     -0.642086
    libinput Accel Speed Default (286):     0.000000
    libinput Accel Profiles Available (287):        0, 0
    libinput Accel Profile Enabled (288):   1, 0
    libinput Accel Profile Enabled Default (289):   1, 0
    libinput Left Handed Enabled (290):     0
    libinput Left Handed Enabled Default (291):     0
    libinput Send Events Modes Available (261):     1, 0
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled (262):        0, 0
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled Default (263):        0, 0
    Device Node (264):      "/dev/input/event5"
    Device Product ID (265):        1133, 4119
    libinput Drag Lock Buttons (292):       <no items>
    libinput Horizontal Scroll Enabled (293):       1
```

I've tried messing with acceleration and no luck.  Ideas?  **ubuntu 18.04; logitech** anywhere mx mouse

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
clear

NAME=Logitech

ID=`xinput list --short | grep -i $NAME | cut -f2 | cut -c4-| head -n1 `
echo $NAME Mouse ID is $ID

xinput set-prop $ID "Coordinate Transformation Matrix" 0.8, 0, 0, 0, 0.8, 0, 0, 0, 1

xinput --list-props $ID
```

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Could you elaborate on this? Perhaps **edit your answer** to explain what you are describing and *why* you are suggesting this script. Thanks!